# How do I get listed in the "featured for tv" section of google play on GTV

Tags: google-tv

I've built an app for google tv, and published it to the google play store. I expected it to be listed in the "featured for tv" section since it was customized for the google tv, but that doesnt seem to be the case.

If i search for my app by name then it is listed in the results, but how can i get it to show up in the "featured for tv" section?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, this is not a technical app development related question, so should not be asked here.

Featured apps are staff picks. However, if you want us to review your app, please join us for one of Hangouts On Air from [Google TV Developers Page](https://plus.google.com/u/0/112249225796277470583/) and tell us more about your app.
We do app reviews in Hangouts on Air once in a while.